# How to simplify when in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm working on an app which use a when statement 
How can I make this more short?

```
when(page) {
   0 -> poster[0].imageURL
   1 -> poster[1].imageURL
   2 -> poster[2].imageURL
   3 -> poster[3].imageURL
   else -> "image not provided"
}
```

Comment: I don't know kotlin, but why don't try to us an `if` which checks if `page` value is between 0 and 3?

Comment: Thanks but kotlin and java are nearly same means the core concept and we can also use java code in kotlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just replace it with a range check:

```
if (page in 0..3) {
    poster[page].imageURL
} else {
    "image not provided"
}
```